# findOne() method of mongoose is not returning the record when i am using a variable for the 'value' of the 'key'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When i am entering a harcoded value (ex. 24409104) in 'value' of eventId 'key' , then everything is working perfectly. But why i am unable to do so by using *response.data.objects[i].id* (from an API)? The data-type is also same as that in the schema of Event. I also tried saving value of *response.data.objects[i].id* in a variable and passing the variable to the eventId as its value, but still 'result' is coming out to be a *null* object. I have checked & the record is present in the database.

```
   const axios = require("axios");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  eventId: Number
});

var Event = mongoose.model("Event",eventSchema);

 var URL = "https://clist.by/api/v1/json/contest/?resource__name=codechef.com&start__gt=2020-6-21T00%3A00%3A00&&end__lt=2020-6-25T22%3A59%3A59&username=<username>&api_key=<api_key>";

axios.get(URL)
.then(function (response) {
for( var i=0 ; i<1 ; i++)
{  
  Event.findOne({eventId: response.data.objects[i].id} , function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("THIS IS YOUR ERROR in event function"+err);
    } else {
      if(result==null)
      {
        console.log("Lets create an event!");
         const event = {
         summary: String(response.data.objects[i].event),
         description: 'CodeChef',
         start:{
            dateTime: response.data.objects[i].start,
            timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata',
         },
         end:{
            dateTime: response.data.objects[i].end,
            timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata',
         },
       }
       calendar.events.insert({calendarId : 'abc@group.calendar.google.com',resource: event},       err => {
         if(err) return console.error('Calendar event creation error: ',err);
         console.log('Calendar event created!');
       }); //calendar event ended

       var identification = response.data.objects[i].id;
       var newEvent = new Event({
         eventId: identification
       });
       newEvent.save(function(err) {
       if (err) 
       {
        console.log("ERROR IN SAVING EVENT CODE "+err);
       }  
       console.log('EventId successfully saved.');
       });
      } //if inside else ends 
      else
      {
        console.log("Event already present!");
      }  
    } 
  }); 
} 
}) 

.catch(function (error) {
  console.log("API URL "+error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally happens if query value is string, and required is number. Try Number(response.data.objects[i].id) instead

Comment: I had already this already but still NOT getting my problem solved.